maui post request not working under android but under windows
I try to program a maui app and I want to use post request. Under windows it is working fine but under android I always get an exception (HttpRequestError.Unknown)
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent("{\"name\": \"John Doe\", \"age\": 30, \"city\": \"New York\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://echo.free.beeceptor.com/sample-request?author=beeceptor");
        msg.Content = content;
        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(msg).Result;
        var result =response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

Screenshot of the above code for reference
I tried it with async and task function but it didn't work.
Maybe someone can tell me, what I'm doing wrong.

This may not be the source of the problem,  but a) use async/await properly, b) Android requires use of https unless explicitly told otherwise

thanks for the answer, with https is working now

By default, MAUI disables cleartext traffic on Android. I noticed your URL uses HTTP; you need to use HTTPS.
If you don’t want to use HTTPS, you need to configure cleartext traffic in Platforms > Android > MainApplication.cs.
Clear-text network traffic for all domains can be enabled by setting the UsesCleartextTraffic property of the Application attribute to true.
#if DEBUG
[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
#else
[Application]
#endif
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownership)
        : base(handle, ownership)
    {
    }

    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}

You can refer to this documentation：Connect to local web services from Android emulators and iOS simulators
